# How can I reset unittest.mock.patch for opening files?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a tar file, containing many .bz2 files. I would like to send each .bz2 file, to a pre-written module for data extraction. This gives...

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BZ2File

As it is inconvenient to write out each .bz2 back to the disc (large file sizes) I have used `unittest.mock.patch` to get around this. This works well. I then need to write out a new file containing processed data, however I get this...

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I believe this is caused by the `unittest.mock.patch`.
I am struggling with the Docs to find a solution to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
import unittest.mock, tarfile, bz2, pickle, gzip

def files():
    with tarfile.TarFile('../2016.tar') as archive:
        for file in archive:
            with bz2.open(archive.extractfile(file)) as f:
                with unittest.mock.patch('builtins.open', lambda f, _: f): yield f

for file in files():
    # some code
    # always write to same output file, in this example
    with gzip.open('out.gz', 'wb') as f:
       pickle.dump('test', f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```